# custom validator in template driven forms Angular

Tags: angular, validation, stepper, clarity

Hi StackOverFlow community,
I m struggling with a custom validation in a template driven forms.
I have a stepper component and I have a unique form that wraps all the groups.
In each step I would like to have the sum of the inputs to be 100%, otherwise it should display an error (like it is for the required and the min and max).

I created an array which it should push every value of the single group, but instead it's pushing each key value and it creates a new array in each input.

Here you have the stackblitz link :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v2-7qtpcz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Thank you in advance :)

edit: The checkPercentage function works fine, but I need to fix the directive which is not working as the checkPercentage function does and I want to have the same behaviour.

Comment: You should move the validator to the `ngModelGroup` ( the clr-stepper-panel tag in this case) and validate the `FormGroup` as a whole.

Comment: @akotech  I tried it and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the `checkPercentage()` method like this:

```
checkPercentage() {
    let singularPercentage: string;
    let myArr: number[];
    let testArr: number[];
    let sum: number;
    for (let allocation in this.allocations) {
      singularPercentage = this.allocationForm?.value;
      myArr = [...myArr, Object.values(singularPercentage)];
      for (let arr of myArr) {
        testArr = Object.values(arr);
        sum = eval(testArr.join('+'));
        if (sum !== 100) {
          this.alert = true;
        } else {
          this.alert = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You are creating new `const` for each 'allocations' and for each 'arr'.